# AWS EC2 high ping and S3 download slow

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, lag

i am new to AWS.
I have some questions want to know.

my EC2 instance :
Instance type : t2.micro - windows server
EC2 region : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
S3 region : AWS write "S3 does not require region selection."
User location : Taiwan

My EC2 ping is too high to my real-time game and S3 download sometimes is very slow.
My network type is WiFi and Cellular networks(3G&4G).
I have test with my local server, 5 users connected and all work fine.
Average 80kb/s per user for EC2.

Questions:
1.Why my client ping EC2, the time always over 100ms?
2.How can i reduce ping under 100ms?
3.Why S3 download speed is very unstable, 50k~5mb?
4.How can i keep download speed stable?

Comment: Lots of variables here, first and foremost being the bandwidth (and stability of bandwidth) available to the client machines.  But also without understanding your full architecture and the network topology for how the calls are routed to the AWS resources, it is really impossible to answer.

Comment: For the bandwidth problem, i tested 5 users connected to sever. It's run total 400kb/s. Will it's too much for EC2 to handle? If it was, how do i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding S3:

It DOES matter where you create your S3 bucket:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

"Amazon S3 creates bucket in a region you specify. You can choose any AWS region that is geographically close to you to optimize latency, minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements. For example, if you reside in Europe, you might find it advantageous to create buckets in the EU (Ireland) region."

On the other hand, "S3 does not require region selection." Means you can access any bucket from any region, though access is optimized for the region where the bucket is located. Bucket location can be set only at the time they are created

Regarding unstable times:

t2.micro is not designed to provide a stable capacity. Instead, its capacity is throttled. Actually any instance type starting with t2 has throttled (non constant) CPU capacity. I suggest you try with a larger instance, like m1.small .

See http://www.ec2instances.info/ , any instance that says "burstable" has a non-stable performance.

Comment: thank you Daniel777. it's very useful info for me :)